# Why does my random number program output garbage?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to display a random number in the array of 5 ints. I have an int distribution from 0 to the size of the array. But whenever I go to output the numbers, sometimes I get a garbage value. Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::random_device seed;
    std::default_random_engine rand(seed());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        std::cout << a[dist(rand)] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Because of undefined behavior - your are accessing an element outside the bounds of array `a`. Use `dist(0, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) - 1)` since the distribution goes from `0` to `X` not `0` to one before `X`.

Answer (score 2):

Array indexes are **zero-based**. For an array of 5 elements the valid indexes are `0..4`. Your distribution returns values in the range `0..5` and is the source of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Because of undefined behavior - your are accessing an element outside the bounds of array `a`. Since the distribution goes from `0` to `X` and not `0` to one *before* `X` you should construct it like so.

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a) - 1);
```